# How do you print multiple different things in a funtion when you can only use one return statement and using print() doesn't work

Tags: python

```
randomm = (random.randint(1, 150))
def randommm():
    for index in range(random.randint(1, 40)):
        if index == 0:
            print("^")
        else:
```

> This is the code I'm trying to solve

```
            print("|")
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I go to print it it says "none" this is because I am using the print statement multiple times in a function and not using the return statement, however as you can see I need to print ("^") and ("|") but if you press return it ends the functions so I don't know how to make it so I can print both things while using a return statement and not a print statement so it doesn't say none.

Comment: why do you need return if you only want to print it? your code works and prints everything correctly. Maybe I don't udnerstand the problem right, but generally a function doesn't need a return statement, it is not mandatory.

Comment: Also, I don't see any `return` statement in your code. Where/why are you putting it?

Comment: well when i execute the funtion it does it but then at the end it says "none" which is quite a problem with what I'm trying to do with it. It is from my understanding that the only way to fix this is put a return statement, which I then checked, when I removed all my print statements but one and then on the one I didn't remove pressed return, I didn't have the problem but if I use a print statement, it once again says none, I am asking how to not use a print statement and still have it print all that out

Comment: You really shouldn't call your function `randommm` it's hardly distinguishable from your variable `randomm`. But as others said, we don't understand what you mean. If you're trying to return multiple stuff, consider returning a `list`, `set` or `dict`

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code along with the index of each print as follows:

```
from random import randint

randomm = (randint(1, 150))
def randommm():
    for index in range(randint(1, 40)):
        print(index, end="\t")
        if index == 0:
            print("^")
        else:
            print("|")
randommm()
```

And it doesn't print 'None'

The output for when the randint returned 20:

```
0       ^
1       |
2       |
3       |
4       |
5       |
6       |
7       |
8       |
9       |
10      |
11      |
12      |
13      |
14      |
15      |
16      |
17      |
18      |
19      |
```

No 'None' gets printed. Perhaps I too (like @Andreas) didn't exactly understand what you meant?